# Is there a way to properly access a private method from a package using Javascript and Typescript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am using the Slack framework [Bolt](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt/blob/master/src/App.ts) and I am running this on a Docker container. I want to publish to an AWS EC2 instance, but need to provide a `/healthcheck` endpoint for AWS EC2. However, the Bolt framework is a wrapper around an express server, and does not readily expose a way to add custom endpoints, e.g. `/healthcheck`.

Currently there is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt/issues/283) about this and a possible solution was posted. The solution suggests that the Bolt `app` has a method called `receiver`, to which a healthcheck function could be passed, but the `receiver` method is **private**, so it is not accessible from outside of the package, e.g. `app.receiver.app.use(healthCheckRouter);`.

Error: `Property 'receiver' is private and only accessible within class 'App'.`

Is there a way to work around this, so I can properly access the class method and add the health check endpoint? Is there a recommended way to handle such cases? Casting `app` to `any` causes type checking to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

The github issue indicates that there are no problems accessing `receiver` when using pure Javascript. To make this work in Typescript you can simply cast the `app` to `any` before accessing the private property.

```
(app as any).receiver.app.use(healthCheckRouter);
```

Comment: yeah, i got that working, but then we lose type checking, is this really the only way?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. You could avoid using the supplied types and introduce your own types for `Bolt`, but that's certainly more work and maintenance on your end for a simple workaround.